# discord.py auto moderator / banned words

Tags: discord.py

I try to create automod system. I find this code, and I try to fix it. It doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. Do you want to give me some help to fix it? I have been working on this for  2 hours, and I cannot figure out the solution. I maybe need to import anything. I don't know...

```py
filtered_words = ["bad", "words", "here"]
filtered_words_counter = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content.lower()
            await message.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
            embed.set_author(name="Banned Word")
            embed.add_field(name="Username:", value=f"{message.author.mention}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Banned Word:", value=f"{word}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Message:", value=f"{message.content}", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text=f'User ID: {message.author.id}')
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID_HERE)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)

            if not filtered_words_counter.get(message.author.id):
                filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] = 1
            else:
                filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] += 1

            if filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] >= 3:
             role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
             await message.channel.send('User was muted')
             await message.author.add_roles(role)
             filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] = 0
```

Comment: what is not working? do you have any error you could share? What's is the console output if you message "something bad happened"

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your code and have made a simpler solution.

```py
import discord

# banned word dictionary
banned_words=[
    "bad_word_1"
]


# On message event 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
       if message.content in banned_words: 
             #you can customize the embed
             embed = discord.Embed(title="Banned Word", description=f"Username: {message.author}" + "\n" + f"Banned Word: {message.content}" + "\n" + f"Message ID: {message.id}", color=0xFF0000)
             embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {message.author.id}")
             # Send the embed
             await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

My solution above is the way I would do it.

However below I have made some edits to your code above.

````py
import discord
import datetime
filtered_words = ["bad", "words", "here"]
filtered_words_counter = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
            embed.set_author(name="Banned Word")
            embed.add_field(name="Username:", value=f"{message.author.mention}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Banned Word:", value=f"{word}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Message:", value=f"{message.content}", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text=f'User ID: {message.author.id}')
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID_HERE)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)

            if not filtered_words_counter.get(message.author.id):
                filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] = 1
            else:
                filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] += 1

            if filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] >= 3:
             role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
             await message.channel.send('User was muted')
             await message.author.add_roles(role)
             filtered_words_counter[message.author.id] = 0  ```
````

Comment: you deserve some good upvotes. not easy to look at plain text and fix it.

Comment: you seem to have known to solve the problem, thank you for taking some of your time to help me :)